# AIMP ran with wine and fixme errors

Tags: wine, mediaplayer

I am running AIMP player with wine and getting errors:

```
wine "N:\\AIMP.exe"
004d:fixme:thread:GetThreadUILanguage : stub, returning default language.
004d:fixme:nls:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 08, 0x3, (nil) 0x3
004d:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 0x3 (nil) 0x31) returning a dummy value (current locale)
004d:fixme:nls:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 038, 0x3, 0x1 0x3
004d:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 0x3 0x1e 0x3) returning a dummy value (current locale)
004d:fixme:wtsapi:WTSRegisterSessionNotification Stub 028 0x0
004d:fixme:uxtheme:BufferedPaintInit Stub ()
004d:fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x3,0x01,0x3c) stub
004d:fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
004d:fixme:nls:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 08, 0x3, 0x4 0x3
004d:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 0x3 0x3 0x3) returning a dummy value (current locale)
004d:fixme:dwmapi:DwmSetWindowAttribute (0002, a, 003, 4) stub
004d:fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet

004d:fixme:file:GetLongPathNameW UNC pathname L"\\\\?\\unix\\mnt\\sdaX\\\041c\\\\0410\043e\\\0417\\Win98\\bachsb~1.rmi"

004d:fixme:file:GetLongPathNameW UNC pathname L"\\\\?\\unix\\mnt\\sdaX\\\041c\\\0410\\\0417\\Win98\\Win98 Theme Sounds\\utopia\\UTOPIA~4.WAV"
004d:fixme:file:GetLongPathNameW UNC pathname L"\\\\?\\unix\\mnt\\sdaX\\\041c\0430\\\0410\043e\\\0417\\Win98\\Win98 Theme Sounds\\utopia\\UTOPIA~4.WAV"

004d:fixme:file:GetLongPathNameW UNC pathname L"\\\\?\\unix\\mnt\\sdaX\\\0418\0415 \0414\ \0420\042f ~ \0411\043d\0435"...

0054:fixme:mfplat:mfsource_CreatePresentationDescriptor (0020)->(0020): stub
0054:fixme:mfplat:mfsource_BeginGetEvent (002)->(002, 0020)

004d:fixme:font:ExtTextOutW flags ETO_NUMERICSLOCAL | ETO_NUMERICSLATIN unimplemented

004d:fixme:dwmapi:DwmIsCompositionEnabled 003

0054:fixme:mfplat:mfsource_CreatePresentationDescriptor (07)->(0): stub
0054:fixme:mfplat:mfsource_BeginGetEvent (07)->(0, 0)

004d:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {1-c9d} not registered
004d:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {f6} could be created for context 0x1
004d:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {ef-d4-4f-8c-3f} not registered
004d:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {ef-d4-4f-8c-3f could be created for context 0x1ef-d4-4f-8c-3f} not registered
004d:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {87-95-40-9a-00} could be created for context 0x1

004d:fixme:dwmapi:DwmInvalidateIconicBitmaps (0002) stub

004d:fixme:explorerframe:taskbar_list_SetOverlayIcon iface 001, hwnd 000, hIcon 000, pszDescription L"" stub!

0053:fixme:wincodecs:JpegDecoder_Frame_CopyPalette (0x,0x): stub
```

Chinese file names are not displayed in AIMP while that's ok in wine file manager. I have installed all fonts through winetricks.

How to fix those errors and incorrect display of chinese characters in AIMP?